# Phonegap onPause event was not working

Tags: android, events, cordova, onpause, notificationmanager

I have developed an android app under phonegap.
I have used local notification plugin. I was trying to get notification from server when app activity was paused.

I tried in javascript:

```
document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false); function onPause() {
// Handle the pause event

setInterval( function() {
    Ext.data.JsonP.request({
            url: 'http://convert4mobile.net/backend/API/qr/push.php',
            callbackKey: 'callback',
            success: function(data)
            {

                if(data.success == true)
                {
                    if (typeof plugins !== "undefined") {
              window.plugins.localNotification.add({
                        date : new Date(),
                        message : data.time+"\r\n"+data.msg,
                        ticker : "A new code was generated",
                        repeatDaily : false,
                        id : 4//data.uid
                });
                }
                }
            }
           });
} , 10000);}
```

And in my main activity :

```
@Override  public void onBackPressed() { moveTaskToBack(true);  return;  } }
```

To pause the event every time when the back button was pressed.

But when the app was getting paused by back button/end call button/screen lock the pause event was not working. I just get it work for only one time.

What I'm missing?